# Using Automapper static API in the latest release?

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper

I've upgraded `Automapper` from 4.2.1 to 5.0.0. I'm using the static API in a WebApi2 project and I'm trying to get the mapping to work, so I tried following [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398318/automapper-mapper-createmaptsource-tdestination-is-obsolete).

So I changed the code to the following:

```
public static class AutoMapping
{
    public static void Config()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(main =>
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
                cfg.CreateMap<MyModel, MyDto>().ReverseMap();
            });
            config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        });
    }
}
```

The above is called from `Global.asax`.

However, I get exception:

> Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate configuration.

What is the correct way to initialize `Automapper`, and do I need to change all my controllers now for mapping?

**EDIT1**

Firstly, the code above must be:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => 
{
    cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
    cfg.CreateMap<MyModel, MyDto>().ReverseMap();
});
Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Secondly, the problem might be in the following method which I use to ignore missing properties:

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreUnmapped<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
{
    var typeMap = Mapper.Configuration.FindTypeMapFor<TSource, TDestination>();
    if (typeMap != null)
    {
        foreach (var unmappedPropertyName in typeMap.GetUnmappedPropertyNames())
        {
            expression.ForMember(unmappedPropertyName, opt => opt.Ignore());
        }
    }

    return expression;
}
```

I'm assuming 'Mapper.Configuration' is not yet configured because the above method is called within `Initialize` which configures the mapping.

Is there an existing method within Automapper itself which I can use instead of the above?

**EDIT2**

Would the following syntax work?

```
cfg.CreateMap<MyModel, MyDto>().ReverseMap().ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Comment: From what event you are calling this function in Global.asax?

Answer (score 2):

Actually your code does nothing now. You have to change it like this:

```
public static class AutoMapping
{
    public static void Config()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
            cfg.CreateMap<MyModel, MyDto>().ReverseMap();
        });
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}
```

**UPD** (after **EDIT1**):

Try to use `expression.TypeMap` instead of `Mapper.Configuration.FindTypeMapFor<TSource, TDestination>()`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It's actually `Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();`. However I still get the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

Setup the Configuration:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>());
```

Then where the mapping should take place:

```
var mapper = new Mapper(config);
OrderDto dto = mapper.Map<OrderDto>(order);
```

You could also expose the 'config' as a static property, and use that in your project. There's also an alternative to create a static 'Mapper' property that is configured. Then you can use that static 'Mapper' property in your project.