# Build xml from entity using automapper

Tags: c#, xml, automapper

I'd like to create an xml snippet from an entity using AutoMapper.
Something along the lines of this:

```
public class SourceEntity
{
    public int MasterId { get; set; }
}

public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<SourceEntity, XElement>()
           .ForMember(
               dest => dest.Element("Asset.ID"),
               options => options.MapFrom(x => x.MasterId));
    }
}
```

When I instantiate the mapper like this:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(
    cfg => { cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfile()); }); 
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

I get this error:

> OneTimeSetUp: AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException : Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type.

I'm ultimately trying to create an XElement like this:

```
XElement retVal = new XElement("Asset",
    new XElement("ID", src.MasterId)
);
```

With a .ToString() returning this:

```
<Asset><ID>789</ID></Asset>
```

Comment: The element "Asset.ID" is not a top level member.  Try just "Asset" instead.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng, I tried that already actually - should have clarified. I do need it to go one level deeper as well. I'll add some expected output to this.

Comment: I think you need to use Initialize.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398318/automapper-mapper-createmaptsource-tdestination-is-obsolete

Comment: Not sure that's it, I'm already using a MappingProfile : Profile and then instantiating the mapper with 
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfile()); });
            _mapper = config.CreateMapper();

Comment: You are getting this error because you are specifying a method for destination member and this is not permitted with AutoMapper. The error message is a bit misleading in this case. Only not nested properties and fields are supported with `ForMember()`. Also, AutoMapper is a wrong tool for creating XML from objects. You should look for conversion code, making `XElement`s from objects, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8375101/8065832).