# How to configure and use automapper 5.1.1

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper-5

I have been looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35256008/automapper-migrating-from-static-api/35256077#35256077), trying to figure out how to get AutoMapper to work. This is what I had earlier

```
public class DomainToViewModelMappingProfile: Profile
{
    public DomainToViewModelMappingProfile()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Institution, InstitutionDataViewModel>()
        .ForMember(vm => vm.InstitutionID, map => map.MapFrom(s => s.InstitutionID))
        .ForMember(vm=>vm.InstituteName,map=>map.MapFrom(s=>s.InstituteName))
        .ForMember(vm=>vm.Circuit,map=>map.MapFrom(s=>s.AdministrativeStructure.AdminStructName))
        .ForMember(vm=>vm.Level,map=>map.MapFrom(s=>s.Level.LevelName))
        );
    }
}
```

Then followed by this

```
 public class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<DomainToViewModelMappingProfile>();
        });
    }
}
```

Finally I have this in my startup.cs

```
// Automapper Configuration
        AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
```

My difficulty now is how to get this working in my controller and whether I am even on the right track. With all the varying information and different approaches all over the place i am terribly confused
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your profile needs to call the non-static method. Change it from `Mapper.CreateMap...` to simply:

```
public class DomainToViewModelMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public DomainToViewModelMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Institution, InstitutionDataViewModel>()
        .ForMember(vm => vm.InstitutionID, map => map.MapFrom(s => s.InstitutionID))
        .ForMember(vm => vm.InstituteName, map => map.MapFrom(s => s.InstituteName))
        .ForMember(vm => vm.Circuit, map => map.MapFrom(s => s.AdministrativeStructure.AdminStructName))
        .ForMember(vm => vm.Level, map => map.MapFrom(s => s.Level.LevelName))
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you just got me going