# How to replace the `AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize` static call in AutoMapper 9.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

In my `Startup.cs` file I have an AutoMapper configuration in my `ConfigureServices` method:

```cs
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(c => c.AddMaps(typeof(Models.MapperProfile), typeof(Data.Ef.MapperProfile)));
```

```cs
namespace Rm.Combo.Api.Models
{
    public class MapperProfile : Profile
    {
        public MapperProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<NewCashoutModel, App.Cashouts.InitiateCashoutCommand>();
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
namespace Rm.Combo.Data.Ef
{
    public class MapperProfile : Profile
    {
        public MapperProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Domain.Cashouts.Cashout, Data.Cashouts.CashoutModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

Seems there was a certain number of breaking changes since I am moving from version `8.1.1` to the `9.0.0`.

I tried to check those particular links:

- [AutoMapper Migrating from static API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35256008/automapper-migrating-from-static-api)
- https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/01/21/removing-the-static-api-from-automapper

But none of them says how to

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/9.0-Upgrade-Guide.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting with 9.0, the static API is no longer available.

You could use AutoMapper via Dependency Injection like below:

1.Install [`AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/)

2.Register a service in `ConfigureServices` on Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MapperProfile));
```

Reference:
[How to using AutoMapper on ASP.NET Core via Dependency Injection](https://www.codementor.io/zedotech/how-to-using-automapper-on-asp-net-core-3-0-via-dependencyinjection-zq497lzsq)