# Automapper map Generics types

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-4

I have 2 class **Data** and **MainData** that I need to map

```
public class Data
{
    public Field<string> Results { get; set; }
    public Field<int> A { get; set; }
    public Field<int> B { get; set; }
}

public class Field<T>
{
 public string Label { get; set; }
 public T Value { get; set; }  
}

public class MainData{
 public string result {get; set; }
 public int a {get; set; }
 public int b {get; set; }
}
```

I've tried to map **Data** to **MainData** using automapper as follows:

```
Mapper.CreateMap(Data, MainData))
.ForMember(dest => dest.result, conf => conf.MapFrom(src => src.results.Value))
.ForMember(dest => dest.a, conf => conf.MapFrom(src => src.A.Value))
.ForMember(dest => dest.b, conf => conf.MapFrom(src => src.B.Value))

var destination = Mapper.Map<Data, MainData>(source);
```

It's never get mapped value to **desination** variable. All i get is new MainData object.

Comment: Add `Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration-validation and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037986/is-automapper-assertconfigurationisvalid-enough-to-ensure-good-mapping

Comment: I think your mapping configuration is correct, I just tested it and got back a MainData with filled-in details. Is there something you missed? (admittedly, this was tested using automapper 5, could that be an issue?)

Comment: same here, tested with automapper 3.3, still working

Comment: @NicholasSizer i am using automapper 4.0.4 version.